# Combinatoric Selection of Passwords

Tags: combinatorics

Give that a password can be $8-12$ characters long and each character in the password can be ether composed of upper case letters, lower case letters, numeric digits, or one of the six special characters * < > ! + =

How many different password are available for this computer system?
there are $5$ cases for length of $8,9,10,11$,and $12$.

What I think: there are 68 different possibilities for each character slot there for for each length we aggregate up like below:
Answer: $68^8 + 68^9 + 68^{10} + 68^{11} + 68^{12}$

Is this correct?

Question 2: How many of these passwords contain at least one occurrence of at least one of the six special characters?

Dealing in cases again, I approached it by finding all the ways to construct the password ($68^n$. where n is for each case length $8,9,10,11,12$) and subtracting all the ways to build a password without any special characters $(62^n)$

Add up all for each case to get answer.

so $(68^8-62^8)+(68^9-62^9)+(68^{10}-62^{10})+(68^{11}-62^{11})+(68^{12}-62^{12})$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Yes. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

To add a formal answer: I agree with @dtldarek, your argument is good for both questions.

Comment: ...[this should be CW](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8683/19341)...